# Generating HTML DOM Element and inserting it into a Razor Page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I currently am working on a asp.net MVC web application in which I have to generate a more or less complex HTML structure and then insert it into a Razor Page. Currently I generate the HTML with string concatenation and then add the string to the ViewBag in my controller, like this:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string htmlString = "<div id=\"example-div\">Some more Stuff</div>" + "Some more HTML strings";
        Viewbag.htmlString = htmlString;
            
        return View();
    }
}
```

And then I access and render that String into HTML inside of my Razor Page like this:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlString)
```

But this can't be best practice. Is there a better way to actually generate a HTML DOM element inside my controller and then load that element into the razor page like a template? If so how?

Thanks

Comment: If possible you can create custom Html Helper and return MVChtmlString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can create your own custom extension helper.

- Create static class
- Create a static method
- Register namespace in the web.config view folder for global access in
  all pages

1. Create one class

```
public static class HtmlHelpers   
{   
     public static MvcHtmlString RenderTemplate(this HtmlHelper helper, string moreHtml=default(string))   
     {   
        MvcHtmlString ohtml = null;
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<div id=\"example-div\">");
        builder.Append("Some more Stuff");
        builder.Append(moreHtml);
        builder.Append("</div>");
        ohtml =new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
        
        return ohtml;
     }  
 }
```

2. Register your class namespace in the web.config inside `namespaces` attribute

```
<add namespace="YOURNAMESPACE"/>
```

3. Open any cshtml page and try to type this keyword.

```
@Html.RenderTemplate() // Default template
@Html.RenderTemplate("<span>More stuff</span>") // Customized template
```